# How to do tabbed view (in picture). Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How to do tabbed view like the picture? Is it possible?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz6gI.png

Comment: that isn't one view, it's 2

Comment: Have a look at the `FlexboxLayout` here https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give photos in row ,column fashion grid layout can be used in which numcolumn attribute is used to specify total number of columns we want to give for all rows